# subsetting n number of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have 3 data.frames:

```
# build first data.frame
Date1 = seq(from = as.POSIXct("1991-01-01 00:00"), 
           to = as.POSIXct("1991-12-31 23:00"), by = 60)
Dat1 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                    x1 = rnorm(length(Date1)))

# build second data.frame
Date2 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("1991-03-01 03:30"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("1991-11-23 22:00"), by = 60)
Dat2 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date2,
                   x1 = rnorm(length(Date2)))

# build third data.frame
Date3 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("1991-02-08 01:30"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("1991-08-23 11:00"), by = 60)
Dat3Matrix <- matrix(data = rnorm(length(Date3)*3), ncol = 3)

Dat3 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date3,
                   x1 = Dat3Matrix)
```

I am now trying to remove the time periods from the three data.frames which are not included in the others (if that makes sense). Eventually I aim to have the three data frames with the same start and end date. How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
newDat1 <- subset(Dat1,Dat1$DateTime %in% Dat2$DateTime)
```

But I was looking for a way to apply this to any number of data frames, for example, the method would still work if I have 10 data frames. The function that I generate should subset all of the data frames and return them with the same start and end date.

So, I would like to generate a function that take any number of data frames and then returns the same data frames with the same start and end date, is this possible?

Comment: You could have made your reproducible example a bit smaller!! 1.2 million rows worth of data? But +1 for a reproducible example :-)

Comment: I agree with @SimonO101 about making a smaller reproducible example. Instead of subsetting, why not `merge`. Convert them all to `xts` and `merge(Dat1, Dat2, Dat3...)` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

- Create a function that takes a `list` of data frames as input
- Use `lapply` to find the min and max of `DateTime` for each element of the list
- Use `do.call` with `rbind` to stitch the results in a data frame
- Find the max of the min, and the min of the max, i.e. the date bounds
- Use `lapply` one more time to do the subset

The code:

```
foo <- function(ldf){
  x <- lapply(ldf, function(x)data.frame(min=min(x$DateTime), max=max(x$DateTime)))
  x <- do.call(rbind, x)
  bounds <- with(x, c(max(min), min(max)))
  lapply(ldf, function(x)x[x$DateTime >= bounds[1] & x$DateTime <= bounds[2], ])
}

x <- foo(list(Dat1, Dat2, Dat3))
str(x)
```

The results:

```
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   252391 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ DateTime: POSIXct[1:252391], format: "1991-03-01 03:30:00" "1991-03-01 03:31:00" ...
  ..$ x1      : num [1:252391] 0.2393 0.6831 1.5666 0.0303 -1.1226 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   252391 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ DateTime: POSIXct[1:252391], format: "1991-03-01 03:30:00" "1991-03-01 03:31:00" ...
  ..$ x1      : num [1:252391] -0.555 0.231 1.212 0.363 -0.943 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   252391 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ DateTime: POSIXct[1:252391], format: "1991-03-01 03:30:00" "1991-03-01 03:31:00" ...
  ..$ x1.1    : num [1:252391] 0.4729 0.8238 1.8854 -0.0781 -1.5236 ...
  ..$ x1.2    : num [1:252391] 1.002 -0.546 0.279 -0.817 -0.844 ...
  ..$ x1.3    : num [1:252391] -0.616 1.313 -0.856 0.648 -0.593 ...
```

Comment: Great, thanks. How would you then get this back to its original format i.e. back to 3 data frames with the start and end time altered?

Comment: At the moment I have used Vars = c("Dat1","Dat2","Dat3") 
for (ii in 1:length(Vars)){
  assign(Vars[ii],do.call(rbind.data.frame, x[ii]))    
} Is this the best possible way?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in such cases I'd always collect all `data.frame`s in a `list` over which you can easily iterate using `lapply`:

```
mydata <- list( Dat1, Dat2, Dat3, ... )
```

If you are looking for the intersection of all DateTime columns, you can do this easily by:

```
datcols <- lapply( mydata, function(x) x$DateTime )
isec <- Reduce( intersect, datcols )
```

Finally you can subset your `data.frame`s by

```
lapply( mydata, function(x) x[ x$DateTime %in% isec, ] )
```